# Hibernate Event Listeners PreUpdate vs PreInsert

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, event-listener

What is the difference between the `PreInsertEventListener` and the `PreUpdateEventListener`? Where do I read about the various EventListeners and what they do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreInsertEventListener` [is](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PreInsertEventListener.html) called before *inserting* an item in the datastore.

`PreUpdateEventListener` [is](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PreUpdateEventListener.html) called before *updating* the datastore.

Some of the *Event Listeners* can be found from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionEventListener.html).